# IllegalMonitorStateException while unlocking ReentrantLock on Android

Tags: java, android, synchronization, reentrantlock

I'm using ReentrantLock with its recommended practise (lock, then actual code in try-block, then unlock in finally, see code example below). Sometimes (very very rare) I'm having java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException exception during unlock. Why it happens? Maybe its somehow related to Android's implementation of Java VM.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:126)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1232)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:430)
at com.example.dummy.backend.model.Model.unlock(Model.java:283)
at com.example.dummy.backend.engine.Engine.removeOldInstances(Engine.java:712)
at com.example.dummy.backend.engine.Engine$ProcessOnResumeWorkInBackground.doInBackground(Engine.java:836)
at com.example.dummy.backend.engine.Engine$ProcessOnResumeWorkInBackground.doInBackground(Engine.java:790)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Code example (slightly simplified):

```
myLock.lock();
try {
        LinkedList<MyClass> myClassInstances = model.getMyClassInstances();
        Iterator<MyClass> iterator = myClassInstances.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                MyClass myClassInstance = iterator.next();
                boolean toBeRemoved = true; // simple condition here
                if (toBeRemoved) {
                        logger.info("Removing old myClassInstance " + myClassInstance.getTimestamp());
                        iterator.remove();
                        Cache.removeMyClassByCodeAndTimestamp(myClassInstance);
                }
        }
} finally {
        myLock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause of this?

Comment: @JoshuaD unfortunately, no. But it was so long ago that I even don't write any Java anymore for years. Do you still experience such an issue?

Comment: Yea,  for me this was happening because I had put unlock() in a finally {} and sometimes the try {} was deciding not to lock, so I would try to unlock something that hadn't been locked.  I added a little flag indicating whether we locked and put an if in the finally, and problem solved.

Comment: I'll make that an answer in a few, I'm on a mobile device at the moment. It looks like you were having the same problem.

Comment: @JoshuaD but lock comes before the try-block.